# Count filled in Rows on MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to count the ips of each users to get a total, as phpbb3 got bots it needs to be filled in rows from the ip.

```
<?
$user_ip = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phpbb_users");
$num_user_ip = mysql_num_rows($user_ip);

echo "Total Users: $num_user_ip "; ?>
```

Comment: Count of distinct IP addresses?

Comment: Just the filled column as phpbb3 got  loads of bots without a ip so I can get the real number of users.

Answer (score 1):

replace this

```
  echo "Total Users: $num_user_ip "; ?>
```

to

```
  echo "Total Users:".  $num_user_ip ; ?>
```

you have to learn how to use quotes.

EDIT:

```
  $user_ip = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phpbb_users GROUP BY user_column");
```

replace `user_column` by your user column

Comment: Still says 48 users but there only 2 users that are not bots and have a IP.

Comment: then you maybe looking for group by , to select distinct users , check my edit

Comment: Ok it gone down to 3, but yet there only 2 filled?

Comment: Not sure why it's 3? but it went down from 48 to 3 so where are getting there... http://prntscr.com/37wmye

Comment: please show the results you getting from your query , i dont need your website with 3 users.

Comment: I did do? I'm getting 3 and there only 2 filled.

Comment: since you didnt want show your result data , then i can say just try add other column to group by which you dont want get doubles example : `GROUP BY user_column , other_column`

Comment: Tried all that, still getting a extra 1 from somewhere.

Comment: sorry i cant guess more, show your table with example data. and wished result then i can help you.

Comment: Thanks I did a sum echo :) Works now. '$first_number = $num_user_email;
$second_number = 1;
$sum_total = $first_number - $second_number;'